# Installing MySQL-python on OSX failing due to missing mysql_config

Tags: python, mysql, pip

I'm attempting to install `MySQL-python` on **OSX** so a program I'm writing can talk to our work database to run and get back query results.

I've run into this error explaining that there is a missing `mysql_config` somewhere. I've come across some other StackOverflow answers but they are geared toward Linux environments.

I've also done a `brew install mysql` but `brew link mysql` is failing. I suspect the issue might being right here.

```
Collecting mysql-python
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Downloading MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 110kB 1.8MB/s
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    sh: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-ev74Js/mysql-python/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "setup_posix.py", line 25, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-ev74Js/mysql-python
```

Comment: It might be easier to build and install from source code.

Comment: What worked for me was downloading from pypi (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysql-connector-python/2.0.4), after unzipping I manually copied the mysql/ dir to site-packages/, then ran setup.py

Comment: What is the error message you get with `brew link mysql`?

Comment: For `brew link mysql` I get `Linking /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.24...
Error: Could not symlink bin/innochecksum
/usr/local/bin is not writable`

Comment: check your mysql path is being added

Answer (score 2):

It appears you don't have write permissions for `/usr/local`, resulting in `homebrew` failing to link. If you're on [OS X 10.11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_El_Capitan)+ there's a good chance that it's reset all the permissions, which you need to change in order to remedy the issue; first try letting homebrew fix things:

**Troubleshooting Homebrew:**

1. Run `brew update` (twice).
2. Run `brew doctor` and fix all the warnings.

**Take Ownership:**

If things fail with permissions errors, check the permissions in `/usr/local`, or perhaps use:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local
```

↳ [Homebrew Troubleshooting document](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Troubleshooting.md#troubleshooting) | [El Capitan and Homebrew document](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/El_Capitan_and_Homebrew.md)

Comment: I'm on  10.10.1 -- `/usr` is `root:wheel` right now. Not sure setting the owner to myself is a good idea honestly as this is root owned directory.

Comment: **Please read the Homebrew documentation** — It explains in more detail what I've already summarized. The directory in question is `/usr/local`, not the top level `/usr`.